# What do the icons next to git branch names mean in Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am using git in Android Studio (IntelliJ). When I select VCS > Git > Branches..., I see:

[image: Git Branches window with a tag icon or star icon to the left of some branch names]

What do the star and tag icons to the left of branch names mean?